# Retrieve value from React-Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the values of the dropdown items, for instance "Action" or "Another Action" based on which is selected using the dropdown button. I know I need to use `onSelect` event but its only giving me the `href` values which is not what I want. Any assistance appreciated.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

```
  <Dropdown.Toggle onSelect={(e)=> {console.log(e)}} variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: Looks like you want a `select`

Comment: I would think that it can be done using the markup they have supplied?

Comment: just posting it here in case anyone lands here, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/select/

Answer (score 1):

> Dropdowns are toggleable, contextual overlays for displaying lists of links and more.

If you read the docs at the link you have provided, [Dropdown.Toggle](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-toggle-props) does not have a prop called `onSelect`.

That said, you could potentially add some state and render your Items via data. That way you could store the last clicked `Item` in state.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const items = ["Action", "Another action", "Something else"];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success">Dropdown Button</Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setSelectedItem(item)}>
              {item}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          ))}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      <pre>selectedItem: {selectedItem}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
```

export default App;

[image: Edit late-butterfly-pwqo6]